# call server side method from handler using uploadify in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, uploadify

I am new to uploadify. I have used it in my customer.aspx page. My code is shown below.

When I select multiple files, it calls the handler named Handler.ashx and executes the ProcessRequest method.

I want to also implement these scenarios

1. how to call my server-side method "insertDB", which is defined inside my
   customer.aspx page, from within my handler.
2. how to pass error in server-side method "errorDB", which is defined in my
       customer.aspx page, from within the handler.
3. after completing all processing, the handler should refresh my customer.aspx page

   $(document).ready(function () {

   ```
       $("#<%=file_upload.ClientID %>").uploadify({
           'swf': 'uploadify.swf',
           'uploader': 'Handler.ashx',
           'cancelImg': 'cancel.png',
           'buttonText': 'Select Files',
           'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
           'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
           'multi': true,
           'auto': true
       });
   })
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to use methods buried away inside other pages. What you should be doing is refactor out the useful code, that does the actual work, into classes and use those classes from both within your ASPX pages and from your ASHX handler.

Answer (score 0):

Necessary to properly design their applications depending on the business processes, 
use classes...

Such as:

my DB class:

```
public class DB {  
         public DB() {
           //constructor   
         }
         public void InsertDB() { 
         // your code   
         }
      ... 
    }
```

in customer.aspx:

```
public void Page_Load() 
{
  DB db = new DB();
  db.RefreshDB();
}

public void SomeProc() 
{
    DB db = new DB();
    db.InsertDB();
}
```

in handler:

```
public class Upload : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
         .....
         DB db = new DB();
        db.InsertDB();
         ....
    }
}


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=file_upload.ClientID %>").uploadify({
        'swf': 'uploadify.swf',
        'uploader': 'Handler.ashx',
        'cancelImg': 'cancel.png',
        'buttonText': 'Select Files',
        'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
        'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
        'multi': true,
        'auto': true,
        'onuploadcomplete': function() {
           window.location = href; // your href to customer.aspx
         }
    });
})
</script>
```

About uploadify events:
http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onuploadcomplete/